# How much garage ventilation is necessary?

Tags: insulation, roof, garage, ventilation

#### The Background

I have a 2-car, attached garage with additional shop space. The garage area is roughly 19x21 while the shop space is roughly 12x27 for a total of ~725 sq ft. See the <sup>very not to scale</sup> picture:
[image]

- The brown circles are the only 2 trees on our property, so we decided to build around them instead of ripping them out
- The green lines approximate the location of doors. Garage door on the south side, entrance to the house on the south/east wall, "people" exit door on the east wall.
- The red lines indicates the approximate location of the ridge line of the trusses that span north to south over the garage portion. These were commercially built trusses of 2 different spans (3 @ 19', the remainder at 33') built out of 2x4 and placed on 24" centers. The "untrussed" portion (roughly 12' x' 15') has stick-built rafters out of 2x4<sup>*</sup> on 16" centers.

A small portion (the east wall and about 1/2 the north wall) was insulated with backed fiberglass batts (backing facing inside the structure) when we built it. The majority, including the roof is *not* insulated. The structure has never been heated or cooled. We're now looking to finish insulating it and will be installing a natural gas fired heater. (Sadly, no AC for the summer.)

We will finish insulating the walls with faced fiberglass batts (unfaced seems to be difficult to find, at least on an initial perusal of my local big-box stores) with the facing on the interior of the structure, or with rockwool (based on price point).

We will also insulate the roof. At this point, we're considering 2" rigid foam panels for the trusses because I haven't been able to find fiberglass or rockwool designed for 24" OC spacing (again, based only on an initial perusal, no serious searching has been performed yet), and the stick-framed roof will be done in fiberglass/rockwool since it is spaced 16" OC. We've considered spray foam for the entire roof structure (only), but are assuming that it will be prohibitively expensive. I will, at least, call for an estimate.

For clarity, we intend to insulate the roof because the garage doesn't have an "attic". The bottom of the roof sheathing is clearly visible from the floor of the garage. There is an area in the trusses where we installed some plywood decking and are using it for storage (as it was designed for), but this is by no means a "ceiling". There is free, unobstructed air flow from floor to the underside of the roof.

The space will only be heated on an as-needed basis, not on a constant 24x7 basis like the rest of the house. If I need heat, I'll turn the heater on and give it a bit to warm up then turn it off when I'm done for they day. I also have no expectation of having it be t-shirt weather in the dead of winter, instead, I expect interior temps in the 50-60°F range. Comfortable enough to work in a sweatshirt and for glue/paint/stain to dry/cure.

I live in the Midwest US (Indiana) where summer highs can be 90°+(F) for days to weeks with humidity to match, and winter lows can get down below freezing for a couple of weeks, too, though it's infrequently that cold that long. We've never had any ice-dam issues on either the garage (no great surprise since it's unheated) or the house itself. We rarely get any significant snow accumulation, especially on our roof, that lasts more than 24 hours. The wind primarily blows from the northwest, any accumulation would be on the southeast corner where the roof abuts the wall of the house.

I've got an OSB roof covered with roofing felt and a new (~5 years old) single layer  of asphalt shingles. If I need to ventilate, I'll be using standard aluminum/steel roof vents. I'd like to use a ridge vent, but with a reasonably new roof, I'd rather not cut the entire ridge & replace it.

#### The Questions

<sup>finally!</sup>

- How much, if any, roof ventilation will I need to provide for this structure?
- If I need to ventilate the roof, do I need to hold the insulation back from the underside of the roof?
- If I need under-roof spacing, holding the foam back is easy (2" foam in a 3.5" space). What is recommended for providing the space in the stick-framed portion?
- Side question: do I need vapor barrier (plastic or faced fiberglass) here? This could be answered in a comment, since it might make the question too broad. ;)

---

<sup>*</sup> If I new then what I know now... In my defense, the internet wasn't loaded with all the answers to life, the universe and everything. They will soon be sistered with larger wood, but hey, it's done quite well for the past 26 years!

Comment: My two cents on vapour barrier, probably not needed, but plastic probably stop any air leaks better.  Underside of roof decking should have ventilation, usually more is better.

Comment: Perhaps lay in Prop-A-Vents  along the roof before laying in the insulation (and providing soffit vents for input and ridge vent for output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft are you talking about something [like this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DUROVENT-Durovent-22-in-x48-in-Raft-Vent-10-Pack/1001364394)? The only other search results for "Prop-A-Vent" were related to boat propellers. If _that_ is what you meant, you'll have to explain the connection... ;)

Comment: We built a garage around a couple of trees years back so props there.   Unfortunately our big oaks died about 3 years later... guessing something to do with the garage/roots/water-supply...

Comment: The short answer is the roof does not need insulation, top of ceiling does, walls do... and if it has done well for that long without attic ventilation then I wouldn't bother with it as you will get little to no return on it (as you are trying to heat not cool).

Comment: It's not actually an attic, @DMoore. The bottom of the roof is clearly visible from the cement floor. There is an area in the trusses where we've installed some plywood flooring for storage, but it is, by no means, an "attic".  I thought about putting that in the original post, then got distracted and forgot to do so.

Comment: I know offhand that rockwool batts are made for 24" OC apps, they just aren't as commonly available at big-box stores because they aren't fly-off-the-shelf items

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - you can order these at big blue and pick them up at store - usually takes about 2 weeks.    The problem isn't insulating but more about what does that roofline look like inside once you do.   If appearances matters you are probably better just setting down a layer of 3/8" plywood sheets and sandwiching the insulation in.   I have seen people use rigid foam sheets for the same thing but your colors are blue, pink or white.

Comment: Is insulating atop the roof deck an option for you, BTW?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel between the decking and the shingles? No. It just had a new roof a couple of years ago and I have no desire to rip that all up "just" for some insulation. Now, if I could get the wife to go for a smooth, _bright_ green roof look, I could just lay the foam on top of the shingles... :)

Comment: About the lack of AC,  a couple candle lit dinners, some flowers and chocolate might help.

Comment: @FreeMan  Yes, those 'roof baffles' are what I meant.  I'm not sure of the spelling of the trademarked model, but builders in this area just call them all (with local accent) "propahvents"